# Is it possible to sort Numpy 2D array like dictionary characters are matching

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort them as given below:

1. First it will check '0th' col & if all values are different, then it will sort by interchanging the rows up & down.
2. If '0th' column contains same values, then it will place them consecutive rows & sorting depends on the value of 1st col. If further matches, process continues f
3. As the row index 2 & 3 have the same values in 0, 1, 2 the column. So by checking at 3rd col it decides the position of row for these two rows. Please help. Thanks in advance.
   NB: As we compare words in dictionary to search, I also want to compare like that.

Input Array:

```
[23.339,    0.015,  0.008,  0.0071,     0.079,  0.001]
[20.759,    0.024,  0.020,  0.0161,     0.1282, 0.030]
[17.352,    0.063,  0.024,  0.0187,     0.1484, 0.039]
[17.352,    0.063,  0.024,  0.008,  0.128,  0.035]
[23.339,    0.015,  0.001,  0.204,  1.819,  0.762]
[17.352,    1.645,  1.045,  0.779,  1.106,  0.821]
[14.556,    0.061,  0.058,  0.0071,     0.1016, 0.005]
```

Output Array:

```
[14.556,    0.061,  0.058,  0.0071,     0.1016, 0.005]
[**17.352,  0.063,  0.024,**    0.008,  0.128,  0.035]
[**17.352,  0.063,  0.024,**    0.0187,     0.1484, 0.039]
[17.352,    1.645,  1.045,  0.779,  1.106,  0.821]
[20.759,    0.024,  0.020,  0.0161, 0.1282, 0.030]
[**23.339,  0.015,**    0.001,  0.204,  1.819,  0.762]
[**23.339,  0.015,**    0.008,  0.0071, 0.079,  0.001]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. This look like standards features of the `pandas` module. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that like so:

```
import pandas as pd


x =[[23.339, 0.015, 0.008, 0.0071, 0.079, 0.001],
    [20.759, 0.024, 0.020, 0.0161, 0.1282, 0.030],
    [17.352, 0.063, 0.024, 0.0187, 0.1484, 0.039],
    [17.352, 0.063, 0.024, 0.008, 0.128, 0.035],
    [23.339, 0.015, 0.001, 0.204, 1.819, 0.762],
    [17.352, 1.645, 1.045, 0.779, 1.106, 0.821],
    [14.556, 0.061, 0.058, 0.0071, 0.1016, 0.005]]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.sort_values(by=list(df.keys()), inplace=True)
print(df)
#        0      1      2       3       4      5
#6  14.556  0.061  0.058  0.0071  0.1016  0.005
#3  17.352  0.063  0.024  0.0080  0.1280  0.035
#2  17.352  0.063  0.024  0.0187  0.1484  0.039
#5  17.352  1.645  1.045  0.7790  1.1060  0.821
#1  20.759  0.024  0.020  0.0161  0.1282  0.030
#4  23.339  0.015  0.001  0.2040  1.8190  0.762
#0  23.339  0.015  0.008  0.0071  0.0790  0.001
```

Comment: Actually I have a 3999x16 dimension array. I have just tried it. It does not work for that.

Comment: I have generated a random array with the same shape as yours and got the correct result in less than `0.4` seconds.

Comment: I had some problem in my code. Really it works fine. Thank you very much. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using numpy following way

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[3,3,5],[3,3,7],[3,3,3],[5,1,1]])  # toy example
sorted_arr = arr[np.lexsort(arr.T[::-1])]
print(sorted_arr)
```

Output:

```
[[3 3 3]
 [3 3 5]
 [3 3 7]
 [5 1 1]]
```

Note that we need to do following actions to use `arr` as `keys` for [numpy.lexsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

- transpose (to get k,N-shaped array, where k is number of different columns to be sorted - in my example 3)
- flip (without that `[::-1]` rightmost column would be most important and leftmost least important)